# Qt; no matching function for call

Tags: c++, qt

Getting this error in a Qt project;

```
C:\Users\Seb\Desktop\SDIcw2\shipHandler.cpp:20: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(QString&)'
     infile.open(qstr);
                     ^
```

Happening in this constructor;

```
SDI::shipHandler::shipHandler(std::string fileName)
{
    QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(fileName.c_str());
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open(qstr);
    while(!infile.eof()) 
    {
        getline(infile,line); 
        shipHandler::lineParse(line);
    }
    infile.close();
}
```

I'm creating initializing the class in another thread by;

```
SDI::shipHandler sh("ships.txt");
```

Only just solved a problem on Qt and its brought about another problem. Really getting annoyed with this and I hate posting a lot on here. Simply trying to pass the file name to open, worked in visual studio but moving here to add the gui. Help is GREATLY appreciated

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QString.html. There is good, freely available documentation out there.

Comment: @juanchopanza Could you give me a nudge in the direction as to where im going wrong?

Comment: Look at the [`ifstream::open`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QString.html) overloads. Does any one of those take a `QString`? Look at the `QSttring` docs. Is there a way of going from a `QString` to something that can be passed to `ifstream::open`?

Comment: Using `QFile` would be a good idea.

Comment: I agree with @Alex (+1), why not use the QT-API (ie `QFile`)?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento New to Qt, wasnt aware of it. I've tried implementing it now and got 

"error: no matching function for call to 'QFile::QFile(std::string&)'
     QFile file(fileName);
                        ^"

Comment: Time you are using `QString+std::ifstream` and another time you use `std::string+QFile`, use `QString+QFile`.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but you copied this code from somewhere? For it seems that you are trying to modify something that already exists and that you are doing so much confusion.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I wrote the code above myself, worked fine in visual studio and have placed placed the files in a Qt project.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento and yes, i'm very confused atm!

Comment: Maybe better totally rewrite (not as long QT is easy, in my opinion) with QtSDK.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento would you be able to give me an example to start with?     std::string line;
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream in(&file);
        while (!in.atEnd()) 
        {
            line = in.readLine();
            shipHandler::lineParse(line);
        }
    } gives me C:\Users\Seb\Desktop\SDIcw2\shipHandler.cpp:19: error: no matching function for call to 'QFile::QFile(std::string&)'
     QFile file(fileName);
                        ^

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51708/discussion-between-horhay-and-guilherme-nascimento)

Comment: Might have to rewrite all the code (it will be easy because you already have the logic), you only have to adapt to changing roles for the function of "QT". But it is no time to study, try @PeterSW answer.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to the QString is just causing you problems.
The compiler error should be solved if you just use `fileName` directly:

```
SDI::shipHandler::shipHandler(std::string fileName)
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open(fileName);
    ...
```

Comment: I had that originally, but got the error; terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check. here is a pic of debug; http://oi57.tinypic.com/nnwvbr.jpg

Comment: First, you don't need to call `open` and `close`. Second, looping over `eof()` is broken.

Comment: I agree with @broken, but it was not necessary a "-1" because he somehow found the problem. Perhaps a comment with suggestions already enough.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento -1 was absolutely necessary, the answer was broken code. Now I can remove it.

Comment: I see -1 when something is absolutely wrong and might not be recovered, but it is a matter of opinion. Anyway thanks for clarifying the issue of the response. (+1 in first comment)